# How to destroy elements (or shorten length) of list array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have the following list:

```
List<MyOwnList> mylist = new List<MyOwnList>();

mylist[0].Name = "Name0";
mylist[0].Class = "Class0";

mylist[1].Name = "Name1";
mylist[1].Class = "Class1";

mylist[2].Name = "Name2";
mylist[2].Class = "Class2";

mylist[3].Name = "Name3";
mylist[3].Class = "Class3";

mylist[4].Name = "Name4";
mylist[4].Class = "Class4";
```

I want to shorten the length or let's say destroy elements from position 3 and 4. I used the following code but it still prints "5" when I do `mylist.Count`

```
for(int i=0; i<mylist.Count; i++)
{
    if(i>2)
    {
        mylist[i] = null;
    }
}
```

I expect it to print "3" when I do `mylist.Count`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do this:

```
mylist[i] = null;
```

you're accually setting `i`th element to null, so you won't change size of your list. Basicaly you will have `null` there:

```
// true
bool elementIsNull = mylist[i] == null;
```

Use [`RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
// remove 2 elements starting at element with index 3
mylist.RemoveRange(3, 2);
```

Comment: I tried mylist = mylist.RemoveRange(3,2) but it shows error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to System.Collections.List<MyOwnList>

Comment: @FrankMartin this means that RemoveRange doesn't return a list but modify the list it's called on.

Comment: It's because `RemoveRange` method doesn't return value (`void`), simply call it like this `mylist.RemoveAt(3, 2);` and you'r list will be modified.

Comment: You have a typo: in your code you used RemoveAt instead of RemoveRange

Answer (score 0):

it's depend how you define "destroy"

if you want to remove the element from the list and "destroy" the cell to reduce the list list you can use the `RemoveAt` - BUT it would shorten the list

if you want to "destroy" the element , GC will take care of that , as long no one is holding reference to this element

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you mean by `Destroy`.

If `MyOwnList` implements `IDisposable`, You would use:

```
int startIndex;
int numberOfItemsToRemove;

mylist.GetRange(startIndex, numberOfItemsToRemove).ForEach(m => m.Dispose()); 
mylist.RemoveRange(startIndex, numberOfItemsToRemove);
```

Otherwise:

```
int startIndex;
int numberOfItemsToRemove;
mylist.RemoveRange(startIndex, numberOfItemsToRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the items in reverse to avoid the indexoutofrange exception and please don't use a property of a list which is going to change in the condition of a loop

try this:

```
        List<MyOwnList> mylist = new List<MyOwnList>();

        mylist.Add(new MyOwnList { Name = "Name0", Class = "Class0" });
        mylist.Add(new MyOwnList { Name = "Name1", Class = "Class1" });
        mylist.Add(new MyOwnList { Name = "Name2", Class = "Class2" });
        mylist.Add(new MyOwnList { Name = "Name3", Class = "Class3" });
        mylist.Add(new MyOwnList { Name = "Name4", Class = "Class4" });

        mylist[0].Name = "Name0";
        mylist[0].Class = "Class0";

        mylist[1].Name = "Name1";
        mylist[1].Class = "Class1";

        mylist[2].Name = "Name2";
        mylist[2].Class = "Class2";

        mylist[3].Name = "Name3";
        mylist[3].Class = "Class3";

        mylist[4].Name = "Name4";
        mylist[4].Class = "Class4";


        int count = mylist.Count;

        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {

            if (i > 2)
            {
                mylist.RemoveAt(i);
                //mylist[i] = null;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(mylist.Count);
```